# Azure Disk Encryption with Terraform for multiple disks

Tags: azure, encryption, terraform, disk

So i can encrypt the os disk with Terrafrom from what i have seen on this site. But how do i encrypt the data disks as well? I thought maybe "VolumeType": "All" would cover all disks but that did not happen. This code works for encrypting os disk... what do i need to do for multiple disks? I am stuck.

Thanks!

```
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}

data "azurerm_key_vault" "keyvault" {
  name                = "testkeyvault1"
  resource_group_name = "testRG1"
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_extension" "vmextension" {
   name                       = "DiskEncryption"
   virtual_machine_id         = "/subscriptions/<sub id>/resourceGroups/TESTRG1/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/testvm-1"
  publisher                  = "Microsoft.Azure.Security"
  type                       = "AzureDiskEncryption"
  type_handler_version       = "2.2"
  #auto_upgrade_minor_version = true

  settings = <<SETTINGS
    {
        "EncryptionOperation": "EnableEncryption",
        "KeyVaultURL": "${data.azurerm_key_vault.keyvault.vault_uri}",
        "KeyVaultResourceId": "${data.azurerm_key_vault.keyvault.id}",                  
        "KeyEncryptionKeyURL": "https://testkeyvault1-1.vault.azure.net/keys/testKey/314c507de8a047a5bfeeb477efcbff60",
        "KekVaultResourceId": "${data.azurerm_key_vault.keyvault.id}",                  
        "KeyEncryptionAlgorithm": "RSA-OAEP",
        "VolumeType": "All"
    }
SETTINGS

  tags = {
    Environment = "test"
  }
}
```

Comment: how are you creating those data disks?  according to https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/managed_disk there are `encryption_settings` on this resource

Comment: In my case I used `encryption_at_host_enabled = true`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested your code for a ***newly created VM with 2 Data Disks*** and it was the same for me as well , If I keep `"Volume: ALL"` then also only OS Disk get ADE enabled and not the data disks if I verify from portal or Azure CLI.

[image]

**Solution for it will be as below :**

Please make sure that the ***attached data disks are added as volumes*** and are ***formatted from within the VM*** before adding the extension from Terraform.

[image]

Once the above is done and you do a `terraform apply` to your code , After successful apply it will reflect on Portal and as well as inside the VM.

[image]

[image]